# Kubernetes Endpoint created for Kafka but not reflecting in POD

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kubernetes-service

In Kubernetes cluster I have created Endpoint pointing to Kafka cluster. Endpoint created successfully.

> Name - **kafka**
>   Endpoint - X.X.X.X:9092

In my Spring Boot application's deployment yaml I have kept environment variable **BROKER_IP**. For this environment variable I have pointed:

```
env:
    - name: BROKER_IP
      value: kafka
```

The POD is in Error state. In my **bootstrap-server** I am getting **kafka** and not the actual Endpoint that was created. Any thoughts?

**UPDATE** - Just tried **kafka:9092** and it worked. So wondering does the ENDPOINT maps to IP only and not the Port? Is my understanding correct??

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you forgot to create the Service object matching the Endpoints? Because you are providing the ip-port pairs yourself the Service would need to be [selectorless](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors).

This works for me:

```
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: kafka
subsets:
  - addresses: [{ip: "1.2.3.4"}]
    ports: [{port: 9092}]
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: kafka
spec:
  ports: [{port: 9092}]
```

Testing it:

```
$ kubectl run kafka-dns-test --image=busybox --attach --rm --restart=Never -- nslookup kafka
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10:53

Name:   kafka.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.96.220.40
```

Successful lookup, ignore *extra* `*** Can't find xxx: No answer` messages

Also, because there is a Service object you get some environment variables in your Pods (without having to declare them):

```
KAFKA_PORT='tcp://10.96.220.40:9092'
KAFKA_PORT_9092_TCP='tcp://10.96.220.40:9092'
KAFKA_PORT_9092_TCP_ADDR='10.96.220.40'
KAFKA_PORT_9092_TCP_PORT='9092'
KAFKA_PORT_9092_TCP_PROTO='tcp'
KAFKA_SERVICE_HOST='10.96.220.40'
KAFKA_SERVICE_PORT='9092'
```

But the most flexible way to use a Service is still to use the dns name (`kafka` in this case).

Comment: just tested with my orignal configuration - kafka:9092 works!!
Still wondering what i am missing. I want to use just 'kafka'
Will try your config and confirm...

Comment: cannot user dns name as bootstrap server in  Spring expects **hostname:port** Already  service and endpoint are created.